# Subclass currently has no primary key relationship

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have JSON that looks like this, which returns a list of `Post`s:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "message": "Hello"
        "urls" : {
            "png" : "https://example.com/image.png",
            "jpg" : "https://example.com/image.jpg",
            "gif" : "https://example.com/image.gif"
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see, I need to make two classes. One for the parent object (`Post`), and one for the object `"urls"` (`PostUrls`).

I've done that like so:

```
class Post: Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var message: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var urls: PostUrls? = nil
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    
    private enum PostCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case message
        case urls
    }
    
    convenience init(id: Int, message: String, urls: PostUrls) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.message = message
        self.urls = urls
    }
    
    convenience required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: PostCodingKeys.self)
        
        let id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        let message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
        let urls = try container.decode(PostUrls.self, forKey: .urls)
        
        self.init(id: id, message: message, urls: urls)
    }
    
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

And

```
@objcMembers class PostUrls: Object, Decodable {
    dynamic var png: String? = nil
    dynamic var jpg: String? = nil
    dynamic var gif: String? = nil
    
    private enum PostUrlsCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case png
        case jpg
        case gif
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: PostUrlsCodingKeys.self)
        
        png = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .png)
        jpg = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .jpg)
        gif = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .gif)
        
        super.init()
    }
    
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
}
```

But, the problem is that I have no relationship between `Post` and `PostUrls`, since there is no primary key to connect the two. Further, this also means that I currently won't be able to control duplicates inside the `PostUrls` table.

So my question is: how can I create a relationship between the two tables, and prevent duplicates in the `PostUrls` table?

Comment: I threw out an answer to handle the first part of your question about relationships. However, preventing duplicates is a whole different question. How would you determine if something is a duplicate - duplicate type? .jpg, .gif etc or duplicate url or both... or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you do **have** a relationship between those objects. Object `Post` contains object `PostUrls`. Realm does not require a primary key to have this kind of relationship, because it creates a primary key behind the scenes. So it uses it, even though you can't access it.

To manually set a primaryKey you have to override a func called `primaryKey()`

```
@objcMembers class DBFilterModel: Object {
    
    // MARK: Properties
    
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    
    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

This way you tell to realm that you want this property to be used as a Unique Key.
To prevent duplicating them, there are 2 ways. First - try to find an object with that `id` already existing in your database, if it exists - don't create it.

Second - by adding conflicts handlers to Realm's save methods. You can set that objects with same ID's will be just modified, but not duplicated. Or you could say that you want to throw an error when you try to insert a duplicated object.

```
realm.add(objects, update: update ? .modified : .error)
```

Comment: This answer is not really correct for the question but it is correct that you have conceptual relationship between your objects. Leveraging a List is the way to go as a solution. I don't think primary keys have a bearing on the answer though; while it will prevent two objects from having the same primary key (they are unique), it doesn't prevent duplicate data within the object, which is what the OP is asking about (I think). So, you could have object with primary key id 1 with a jpg pointing to www.somejpg.com and then an object with primary key id 2 pointing to the exact same thing.

Comment: @Jay nobody is preventing usage of an URL as a primary key, so you will have unique URLs. Or just check manually before adding them.

Comment: or you could use a compound key in Realm, like in a regular database

Comment: Understood. A url is a challenging primary key as if it changes (which happens) it invalidates that object and the rest of the data. Perhaps the answer can be expanded and clarified to address the question(s) a) Create a relationship between the Post objects and its types and URLS and b) prevent duplicate data? Can you provide some code that does that? It's currently using an integer primary key which won't create a relationship or prevent a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The question has two questions within

1. How do you create a relationship between the two 'tables'
2. prevent duplicates

Let me address 1)

Start with a class to hold the image type (.jpg etc) and then the url

```
class ImageUrlClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var imageType = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageUrl = ""
}
```

and then the main class which handles decoding

```
class Post: Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var message: String = ""
    let urlList = List<ImageUrlClass>()
   
    ...edited for brevity

    convenience init(id: Int, message: String, urls: [String: String]) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.message = message
        
        //create a ImageUrlClass from each dictionary entry
        for url in urls {
            let key = url.key
            let value = url.value
            let aUrl = ImageUrlClass(value: ["imageType": key, "imageUrl": value])
            self.urlList.append(aUrl)
        }
    }

    convenience required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: PostCodingKeys.self)

        let id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        let message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
        let urls = try container.decode([String: String].self, forKey: .urls)

        self.init(id: id, message: message, urls: urls)
    }
}
```

The above will create a Post object with a List property that contains the image types and urls (a List behaves very similar to an array)

You could further this by adding a [LinkingObjects](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships) property to the ImageUrlClass which would automagically create an inverse relationship to the Post object when objects are added to the List. Not sure if you need that but it's available.

You can this do this to print out the post properties

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
let post = try! decoder.decode(Post.self, from: encodedData)
        
print(post.id)
print(post.message)
for url in post.urlList {
    let a = url.imageType
    let b = url.imageUrl
    print(a,b)
}
```

which would results in an output like this

```
1
Hello
jpg https://example.com/image.jpg
png https://example.com/image.png
gif https://example.com/image.gif
```